# Error while using php-tmdb-api for TheMoviesdb.org API

Tags: php, api, themoviedb-api

My problem is that i want to use TheMoviesDB.org API for a project in PHP and found that there are already some Wrappers Libraries available for this purpose.

I selected **php-tmdb-api** by *Michael Roterman* for this purpose. I followed the instructions and setup API key for the library to work

However, whenever i try to see the examples i get this error:

> Warning: require_once(../../../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Here are the some links regarding my problem:

[PHP-TMDB-API](https://github.com/wtfzdotnet/php-tmdb-api/)

[WRAPPING LIBRARIES](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/wrappers-libraries)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I've found you question this late and do hope you have solved this problem meanwhile.

You should have installed composer and install all the dependencies it requires. First off install composer ( https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-nix ), assuming your on *nix.

Then you simply run composer.phar install from the project's root directory and it should set up all your dependencies. After that everything should work flawlessly.

Feel free to contact me on the google+ community! https://plus.google.com/communities/113544625011244846907